# Inventory Balance with Gurobipy

Tags: python, optimization, indexing, gurobi

I would like to get the inventory balance in the oponed facility (c) such that the Inventory at time t is equal to previous one, plus the inflow minus the outflow

The other issue is with indexing in python.

For instance, if (t) which is time in months,and it's range (0,3) then, t-1 is -1 which gives an error.

$INV_{c,t}$ is the inventory at time (t)

$INV_{c,t}$ is the inventory at time (t-1)

```
$INV_{c,t}=INV_{c,t-1}+\sum{QS}_{c,t}+\sum{QM}_{c,t}-\sum{QS}_{c,t}$
```

I have tried to create a list with zeroes, but I could not make it automated.

Comment: The inventory at `t=-1` should be exogenous. You can observe that.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen could you please give an example, I have created initial inventory, and put it to zero, the lenght of the defined list of time (months) cannot capture it!